# Practical Development with VS2012, SSDT, and TFS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, tfs, sql-server-data-tools

With SSDT/VS2012/TFS, stored procedures are saved as CREATE scripts.

I also have database references, which I use in some scripts like
select * from [$(MyOtherDatabase)].[dbo].[someTable]

If I open a stored procedure in my project and execute it, it executes the CREATE script, which will error out. Also, variables such as $(MyOtherDatabase) do not get resolved.

What is the best way to deal with these problems?

Do I manually change the script to an ALTER? Do I manual replace all my variables with their values? And then when I check the procedure back into TFS, do I have to reverse all those operations? Or do I need to do a publish for everything?

Answer (score 2):

**Q:Do I manually change the script to an ALTER?**

No, when you compile and publish your project it will automatically determine the appropriate DDL.

**Q:Do I manual replace all my variables with their values?**

No. You can change or set the variables values inside of each configuration you are using i.e Local,Test,Stage...

**Q:Do I need to do a publish for everything?**

When you publish it will create a script or apply the changes directly to the database based on your configuration file. You select your configuration which will have the target database set in it and then the publish will create a script or apply the changes directly. So it depends on what environment you are targeting.

If you are using VSDT or Database projects then your deployment is designed to be handled by compiling and publishing your project either directly or via a script created.

You loose core functionality and incorrectly are using database projects if you change the create statement to an alter statement. When you compile your project it will determine if the script should use a Create or alter DDL statement and will automatically make this decision based on the database you are targeting for your deployment.

[Database Project Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272681%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

[How to: Change Target Platform and Publish a Database Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272687%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Comment: So how can I edit my stored proc and "apply" it to the database so that I can then execute it? What steps do I take to do that?

Comment: You would make your changes to the Table within SSDT/VS2012 and it will let you know if there are any dependencies affect by the change. If not then you compile the project. If successful then you can chose the option to deploy which will again create a script or apply changes directly to target database based on what configuration you are using...debug/release . Check out this link for more info as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx . Hope this helps.

Comment: Check out the links I added as well for help to the answer

Comment: I appreciate your help. However, let me clarify: I have a stored procedure. It is saved as a "create" script. I want to edit the stored proc. What specifically are the steps to "alter" my stored proc from within Visual Studio and have it applied tot the database?

Comment: If you do your changes in VS, then do a schema compare with your database all differences between your project in VS and the database will show up. You can then choose the alterations you want to apply to the database and click update.

Comment: @Nighty_, you're basically suggesting what I say in my last sentence of my original post: that I should publish to the database. Seems like an unfortunate requirement.

Comment: Do you have a database project with lots of tables and db objects or are you just opening a script and need to make a change and apply it to a database? If no db project then you are basically using SSMS. If a db project then build the db after the change and target the db that needs the update and let it apply the change or create the script. Otherwise do what @Nighty_ suggested and do a DB scheme compare and apply the update.

Comment: Yes, I have a project and I'm using TFS. It seems like a lot of added steps--publishing/schema compare--just to apply a change to my stored proc to the database. However, if that's the way it is, then that's the way it is.

Comment: It ensures that your project is the gold standard and ensures that all the databases that will need the changes throughout the sdlc get kept in sync. Otherwise it can be a nightmare maintaining database's. Once you do it a couple of times you will find that it is not that tedious and is in fact more like compiling code and deploying regular code.

Comment: Other people may be modifying different stored procedures. I don't want to step on them. Therefore, I have to uncheck everything in the schema compare (or publish script) except for the one change I just made. This is not user-friendly.

Comment: This is where TFS and the DB project will help you the most. Before you check in your stored procedure changes and publish/deploy them you perform a get latest to ensure you are working from the latest file version. If another teammate has update the sp you will get the changes and not overwrite theirs. It makes what is checked into TFS the gold standard, so to speak and helps everybody on the team.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this trick I use with UDF's.

I had problems dropping them and re-adding them (what I do with stored procedures most of the time).  So I came up with the idempotent solution below.

```
Use [$(DBName)]
GO

:Error $(ErrorOutputFileFromCommandLine)  

/*
Create a stubbed version if it does not exist... if it exists, this could shouldn't run, thus not violating permissions
*/

if NOT exists (select *  from sysobjects 
    where id = object_id('dbo.udfMySuperCoolUDF') and sysstat & 0xf = 0)
    BEGIN
        print 'Creating the stubbed version of dbo.udfMySuperCoolUDF'
        EXEC ( 'CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udfMySuperCoolUDF (@i as smallint , @j as smallint ) RETURNS bit AS BEGIN RETURN 0 END')
    END
GO


ALTER FUNCTION dbo.udfMySuperCoolUDF (@ValidationLookupCategoryKey smallint , @ValidationLookupKey smallint  )
    RETURNS bit AS
    BEGIN
        declare @exists int

        select @exists = 0

        /* Logic Here */

        return @exists
    END
```

Second.

Research "sqlcmd" mode.  Keep the $(MyVariable) "as is", and learn how to manipulate them in sqlcmd mode (inside SSMS) and with deployments (sqlcmd.exe).